# To fade only a part of a image in html

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I have an image and I want to fade the central circular portion of the image to be shown clear and the rest of the portion to be faded.

I tried with canvas as well as by taking two divs and making one of them fade,
but not working.

Following is the pattern i need, with the area out of the circle to be faded. Please Help!!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a starting point for you to get an image that's clear center and fade-to-color outside:

- position 2 canvases -- one on top of the other
- draw the image on the bottom canvas
- fill the top canvas with your color (blue,etc)
- use a combination of scaling, shadowing and compositing to "reveal" the image underneath

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/HtL4P/

[image]

Example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{position:absolute;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var canvas1=document.getElementById("canvas1");
    var ctx1=canvas1.getContext("2d");

    var img=new Image();img.onload=start;
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/landscape2.jpg";
    function start(){
        canvas.width=canvas1.width=img.width/3;
        canvas.height=canvas1.height=img.height/3;
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,0,0,img.width/3,img.height/3);
        ctx1.fillStyle="dodgerblue";
        ctx1.fillRect(0,0,canvas1.width,canvas1.height);
        ctx1.save();
        ctx1.scale(3,1);
        ctx1.globalCompositeOperation="destination-out";
        ctx1.arc(-100,120,40,0,Math.PI*2);
        ctx1.shadowColor="white";
        ctx1.shadowBlur=60;
        ctx1.shadowOffsetX=500;
        ctx1.fill();
        ctx1.restore();
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=356 height=237></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas1" width=356 height=237></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello markE, i dont't need the color (which is doggerblue) but the image to be faded. Please help.